# What is the point of IsDefined<TEnum>(TEnum value)?

Tags: c#, enums

In enum.cs there are two implementation of enum.IsDefined, the first one I always use is IsDefined(Type enumType, object value) works perfectly fine

But there is an other IsDefined, this one :

```cs
public static bool IsDefined<TEnum>(TEnum value) where TEnum : struct, Enum
{
    RuntimeType enumType = (RuntimeType)typeof(TEnum);
    ulong[] ulValues = Enum.InternalGetValues(enumType);
    ulong ulValue = Enum.ToUInt64(value);

    return Array.BinarySearch(ulValues, ulValue) >= 0;
}
```

*source : Enum.cs*

Is there any way this method could return false ?

It looks like a bug to me, this function should accept an Enum in parameter, not a TEnum. Or am I completely missing the point here ?

I would expect this function to work just like the overload, just being a synthaxic sugar

Comment: For example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qgh2l0

Comment: Did not thought of that. But isn't it a bad practice to cast before checking if the value is defined ?

Comment: The cast will *always* succeed. This method allows you to check whether a particular number is defined as an element of the enum without any boxing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Etienne de Martel

Yes it can return false, the idea is to cast before checking if the value is defined :

```
using System;

public enum E
{
    V = 0
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        E e = (E)1;
        Console.WriteLine(Enum.IsDefined(e));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The version that accepts `object` is OK, but it forces a "boxing" operation, i.e. it forces a heap allocation. In isolation, affordable, but: allocations add up. At the time, .NET didn't have generics, so: it was the best that could be done.

Generics serves as a mitigation against boxing (for value-types), so here it is used to avoid that overhead. It also makes calling it easier, since you don't need to specify the type *at all* in most cases (except perhaps when passing the literal zero). The compiler can infer the generics from the type of the argument.

Comment: Does that mean the best practice is actually to use the generic method and cast before then check if Defined after ?

Comment: @Ashijo if you mean cast from integer: then "yes" - casting between integer and enum is free (enums are just integers with compiler prettiness), so has no cost; boxing however is a real cost